# Color Guessing Game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a RGB color guessing game.
I want to have 3 levels Easy, Medium and Hard.

When the player picks `Easy` I want 3 squares to show, if they want `Medium` I want 6 squares and `Hard` should have 9 squares.

I have this code but I am having troubles, when I select `Medium` or `Hard` 9 squares come up.

Also in my .html file in the div id="container" is there a better way to write the logic rather than just putting in `<div class="square"></div>` 9 times?

One more question, can you write a ternary operator with more than 3 conditionals?  Or would it just be easier to write a if/else statement or would a nested ternary work also?

I am not looking for the answer, I am looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

```js
var numSquares = 9;
var colors = [];
var pickedColor;
var squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById('colorDisplay');
var messageDisplay = document.querySelector('#message');
var h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
var resetButton = document.querySelector('#reset');
var modeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.mode');

init();

function init() {
  setupModeButtons();
  setupSquares();
  reset();
}

function setupModeButtons() {
  for (var i = 0; i < modeButtons.length; i++) {
    modeButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      modeButtons[0].classList.remove('selected');
      modeButtons[1].classList.remove('selected');
      modeButtons[2].classList.remove('selected');
      this.classList.add('selected');

      this.textContent === 'Easy' ? (numSquares = 3) : (numSquares = 9);

      reset();
    });
  }
}

function setupSquares() {
  for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    //add click listeners to squares
    squares[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      //grab color of clicked square
      var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
      //compare color to picked color
      if (clickedColor === pickedColor) {
        messageDisplay.textContent = 'Correct!';
        resetButton.textContent = 'Play Again?';
        changeColors(clickedColor);
        h1.style.backgroundColor = clickedColor;
      } else {
        this.style.backgroundColor = '#232323';
        messageDisplay.textContent = 'Try Again';
      }
    });
  }
}

function reset() {
  colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);
  //pick new random color from array
  pickedColor = pickColor();
  //change colorDisplay to match picked color
  colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
  resetButton.textContent = 'New Colors';
  messageDisplay.textContent = '';
  //change colors of squares
  for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    if (colors[i]) {
      squares[i].style.display = 'block';
      squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    } else {
      squares[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  h1.style.backgroundColor = 'steelblue';
}
resetButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  reset();
});

function changeColors(color) {
  //loop through all sqaures
  for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    //change each color to match given color
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}

function pickColor() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  return colors[random];
}

function generateRandomColors(num) {
  //make an array
  var arr = [];
  //repeat num times
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    //get random color and push into arr
    arr.push(randomColor());
  }
  //return that array
  return arr;
}

function randomColor() {
  //pick a "red" from 0-255
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  //pick a "green" from 0-255
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  //pick a "blue" from 0-255
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  return 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #232323;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Avenir";
}

.square {
  width: 30%;
  background: purple;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
  border-radius: 15%;
  transition: background 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.6s;
}

#container {
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.1;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  background: steelblue;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

#colorDisplay {
  font-size: 200%;
}

#message {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}

#stripe {
  background: white;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.selected {
  color: white;
  background: steelblue;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: steelblue;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: inherit;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  outline: none;
}

button:hover {
  color: white;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<h1>The Amazing
  <br>
  <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span>
  <br> Color Game
</h1>

<div id="stripe">
  <button id="reset">New Colors</button>
  <span id="message"></span>
  <button class="mode selected">Easy</button>
  <button class="mode">Medium</button>
  <button class="mode">Hard</button>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: No, not yet still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have this code but I am having troubles, when I select Medium or Hard 9 squares come up.

Yes, this will happen since your ternary condition is written as `this.textContent === 'Easy' ? (numSquares = 3) : (numSquares = 9);` If `textContent` is Easy, it will take `numSquares` as 3 and whenever it isn't Easy (Medium or Hard), `numSquares` will be 9.

To resolve this I suppose you could next the ternary condition like [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/use-multiple-conditional-ternary-operators/192928) or just write an if else block.

> Also in my .html file in the div id="container" is there a better way to write the logic rather than just putting in 9 times?

I've just experimented a bit with Javascript so I'm not sure, but I guess you'll have to just write it out 9 times :( Correct me if I'm wrong, but you'll need a templating engine like ejs to render stuff like this by writing it once and putting it in a loop!

Answer (score 0):

Some things I noticed...

> I want to have 3 levels `Easy`, `Medium` and `Hard`.

When you initialize the game, I think you should do it in `Easy`, and its variable in `numSquares = 3`.
I see you initialize it to `Easy` but its value is `9`.

> I have this code but I am having troubles, when I select Medium or Hard 9 squares come up.

The problem comes from not giving the value `9` when the user selects `Medium` and `Hard`.
This value comes as an escape from the ternary condition. `"else"`.

> Also in my .html file in the div id = "container" is there a better way to write the logic rather than just putting in 9 times?

You did it in a subtle way. In the future, your code may not be robust, maintainable, etc., but that comes from the `"model"` you want to implement.
If you know that in the future that amount of `squares` will be maintained for each level, keep it that way.
If the information inside the `squares` is delicate, you should not render them.
It all depends on the `"model"`

> Can you write a ternary operator with more than 3 conditionals?

You can add the conditionals you want, but it is not good practice.

> Or would it just be easier to write a if/else statement or would a nested ternary work also?

You must do a conditional `if`, this would be clearer. Not everything must be done forcibly in one line of code.

You can even do a `Switch`, just to make it clearer.
Link: [Switch Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

I hope this can help!